# Jquery Gallery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using Jquery Gallerific Gallery :
http://www.twospy.com/galleriffic/index.html

To show a gallery. However after thumbnails have been loaded no image seems to load and loading gif appears constantly. Here is the url:
http://contestlancer.com/salon/gallery.php

Can you tell me what could be the problem?
Ahmae

Comment: please post some code (or link to jsbin) so we can see what you're doing

Comment: You have an error `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'opacityrollover' ` line `317`. You may have forgotten to include a file

Comment: Hi, I thought code would be too redundant . I am using simple implementation copy and pasting from the demo website of the gallery. @Gevious

Comment: You seem to miss a few images? That is where the error is coming from (it can't find the object) and that's probably why your code doesn't continue and keep showing the loader icon.

Comment: you are missing `jquery.history.js` and `jquery.opacityrollover.js`

Comment: @Spokey added both but still same problem please chedck

Comment: @AhmarAli The gallery is working for me now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok found the problem. I was including the files opacityrollover.js and history.js in the header.php but function cal to load gallery was in footer. So moving the above mentioned files to footer did the trick. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 1):

after this
  js/jquery.galleriffic.js"

add below code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.opacityrollover.js"></script>
```

include this script in your index.php file

Comment: I have added the file but still same problem persists. Please Check